# ASP.NET URL-rewriting works in Development Server but not in local IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5, aspnet-development-server

I'm programming ASP.NET using visual studio 2010 and IIS 7.5

I have URL-rewriting in Global.asax (RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute). It works in Development Server but not in IIS.

Is there a configuration for this in IIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a webconfig for it... You don't *need* the remove/add part, that's just showing how you'd explicitly *only* include this module.

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

system.web:

```
 <httpModules>         
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
 </httpModules>
```

Comment: actually just <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
did the trick.

Comment: yeah, this is just demonstrating the explicit invocation of this particular module.